# .NET : is updating a reference type variable concurrency safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency

Can a reference type variable be updated to point to a completely new instance of its class safely in presence of read-only concurrent access to it or does it require being guarded somehow?

Comment: Are you sure the question has been answered? If you go through all comments and all the answers I'd say no clear answer was in the end provided. Blocking questions from getting answers only because someone thinks an answer was already provided is very unfortunate.